# Dynamically show the control and content on next screen after ComboBox change in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When I run this code first time everything works as expected. But once you select `Sonitor` and then select `BBraun`, `Sonitor` controls (label and textbox) doesn't go away they are still on screen.

```pascal
[Code]
var
  VendorPage, VendorHostPage: TWizardPage;
  VendorText: TNewStaticText;
  VendorEdit: TNewEdit;
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;
  
procedure ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0:
    begin
      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'AssetTracking connects to the BBraun server to recieve the HL7 data';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'BBraun HL7 port:';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorEdit := TNewEdit.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorEdit.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorEdit.Left := ScaleX(200);
      VendorEdit.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface; 
      
    end;
    1:
    begin
      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'AssetTracking connects to RTLS server to recieve streaming location data';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'Centrak RTLS Server IP address:';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorEdit := TNewEdit.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorEdit.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorEdit.Left := ScaleX(200);
      VendorEdit.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;
      
      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Top := ScaleY(50);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'Centrak RTLS Server port:';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorEdit := TNewEdit.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorEdit.Top := ScaleY(50);
      VendorEdit.Left := ScaleX(200);
      VendorEdit.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;      
    end;
    2:
    begin
      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'AssetTracking connects to RTLS server to recieve streaming location data';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'Sonitor RTLS Server IP address:';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorEdit := TNewEdit.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorEdit.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorEdit.Left := ScaleX(200);
      VendorEdit.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;
      
      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Top := ScaleY(50);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'Sonitor RTLS Events port:';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorEdit := TNewEdit.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorEdit.Top := ScaleY(50);
      VendorEdit.Left := ScaleX(200);
      VendorEdit.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;   
           
      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Top := ScaleY(75);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'Sonitor RTLS API port:';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorEdit := TNewEdit.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorEdit.Top := ScaleY(75);
      VendorEdit.Left := ScaleX(200);
      VendorEdit.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface; 
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  InstallJava: Boolean;
  
begin
  VendorPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'RTLS HW Data Source Configuration', '');
  
  VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorPage);
  VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
  VendorText.Caption := 'Please select the RTLS hardware vendor to install:';
  VendorText.AutoSize := True;
  VendorText.Parent := VendorPage.Surface;

  VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorPage);
  VendorText.Top := ScaleY(25);
  VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
  VendorText.Caption := 'RTLS Vendor';
  VendorText.AutoSize := True;
  VendorText.Parent := VendorPage.Surface;

  ComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(VendorPage);
  ComboBox.Top := ScaleY(25);
  ComboBox.Left := ScaleX(100);
  ComboBox.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  ComboBox.Parent := VendorPage.Surface;
  ComboBox.Style := csDropDown;
  ComboBox.Items.Add('BBraun');
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Centrak');
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Sonitor');
  ComboBox.ItemIndex := 0;
  ComboBox.OnChange := @ComboBoxChange;

  VendorHostPage := CreateCustomPage(VendorPage.ID, 'RTLS HW Data Source Configuration', 'Provide Connection details to Teletracking RTLS');
  
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0:
    begin
      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'AssetTracking connects to the BBraun server to recieve the HL7 data';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorText := TNewStaticText.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorText.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorText.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];
      VendorText.Caption := 'BBraun HL7 port:';
      VendorText.AutoSize := True;
      VendorText.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface;

      VendorEdit := TNewEdit.Create(VendorHostPage);
      VendorEdit.Top := ScaleY(25);
      VendorEdit.Left := ScaleX(200);
      VendorEdit.Parent := VendorHostPage.Surface; 
    end;
  end;
 
end;
```

Expected behavior after selection combobox value:

[image: BBraun behaviour]
[image: Centrak behaviour]
[image: Sonitor behaviour]

PS: If you can't see the images on browser please download it, the code has written for first two screen `ComboBox` and Next screen based on selection not for rest of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. Assigning an object variable in Pascal Script does not destroy the object to which the variable was pointing to previously.

You have to do that explicitly. Like:

```pascal
if Assigned(VendorText) then VendorText.Free;
```

---

Though more common way to implement, what you want, would be to create the controls once at the beginning, hiding/showing and/or changing their caption, as the combo box selection changes. Such solution would require significantly less code.